# Create a IBindingGridView list for binding source using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filtering

I am creating a windows form application. I am using AdvanceDataGridView for filtering and sorting purpose. I have written this code:

```
Private Sub AdvancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterStringChanged
        Me.BindingSource1.Filter = Me.AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString
    End Sub
```

And in the load

```
 Using db As New Entities 
        BindingSource1.DataSource =  db.tableName.ToList
        AdvancedDataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    End Using
```

But still I am not getting filtered records in grid.
After searching I found that to enable filtering we need to use IbindingSourceList. But how to create that type of data? Or is there any other way to make this filtering work.

I am using VB.net.

Comment: You should be assigning the `DataTable` itself as the `DataSource`.  `DataTable` implements `IListSource` and it's `GetList` method returns its own `DefaultView`, which is a `DataView` object, which implements `IBindingListView`.  You probably ought to know the names of things you need to use.  It's `IBindingListView`, not `IBindingGridView` or `IBindingSourceList`.  Neither of those exist.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. How can we create DataTable using the entity,

Comment: You're getting the data using `db.tableName.ToList` so presumably there's a `DataTable` in there to begin with, so you could use that.  If you don't have a `DataTable` or don't want to expose the one you have then you would have to define your own type that implements that interface.  You might start that by inheriting `Collection(Of T)`.